# Java interface and abstract class

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

We had a Java test today and there was a heated discussion about the right answer. Can you help me to find the right answer with a simple explanation.

Question: What is wrong with this Java code?

```
abstract class Fluffy {
}

interface Animal {
}

class Cat extends Fluffy implements Animal {
}

class Dog extends Fluffy implements Animal {
}
```

Options

1. Animal must be an abstract class and Fluffy must be an interface
2. Fluffy must implement Animal
3. Animal must be an abstract class
4. Fluffy must be an interface

*You can select only one answer*

Comment: What happens when you try compiling the code? What do *you* think is wrong and why?

Comment: 5. none of the above

Comment: @azurefrog beat me to it :)

Comment: I suspect you mis-read the question as there is nothing wrong with the code and none of the options apply.

Comment: I would invite your professor here and ask him why does he/she write these nonsensical questions?

Comment: I assume that `Cat` and `Dog` should be `Animal`s that implement `Fluffy`, but it compiles so...

Comment: It might make more sense to have the `Animal` as an abstract class and `Fluffy` as the interface, but there is no technical reason this is needed.

Comment: "must" is too strong, but I usually see abstract classes implementing the interface and providing default implementations for some or all of its methods.  See the java.lang.util.collections package for examples (e.g. List and AbstractList, Map and AbstractMap).  So my first thought was "Fluffy should implement Animal".  This question is confusing because there are no methods anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a programming perspective, there isn't really anything wrong with the code.

I guess what your teacher was getting at is that Fluffy should be an interface and Animal should be the abstract class, but that's more a **design** issue than a **code** issue. You can probably come up with arguments for either side, using imaginary scenarios since no scenario has really been given.

Comment: *that's more a **design** issue than a **code** issue* right in the Programming 101 class.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer unlike some others